# How invoke method of the object created from C++ in QML?

Tags: c++, qml

I need dynamically run JavaScript to operate some C++ object from the simulation.

Example:

```
class CppToQML : public QObject{
    Q_INVOKABLE CppClass* getObj(int i);
    QList<CppClass*> mList;
}
```

First, i have a `CppToQML` class which is registed into QML.

`qmlRegisterType<CppToQML>("CppToQML", 1, 0, "CppToQML");`

The `CppClass` is created in C++ side and stored in `CppToQML mList`

```
class CppClass : public QObject {
    Q_INVOKABLE void sayHello();
}
```

I am trying to do this in QML javascript:

```
CppToQML {
    id: cppToQML
}

//javascript
cppToQML.getObj(0).sayHello();
```

Problem is QML can not recognize `CppClass` pointer as a data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For QML to recognize the class you must register it:

```
qmlRegisterType<CppClass>("CppToQML", 1, 0, "CppClass");
```

or:

```
qmlRegisterType<CppClass>();
```